# Springboot property typemismatch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, type-mismatch

I have a common issue and none of all the other similar questions on the forum helped me sofar. Pls bear with me, im still learning.

l have a Spring boot app.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConsoleApp implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Value("${numberOfDocs:10}")
    private int numberOfDocuments;
    @Value("${filePath:testdoc-al.pdf}")
    private String filePath;
```

Unfortunately the first property that I declare doesn't work due to type mismatch from String to int. The other  works just fine. my application.properties looks like this:

```
#file path.
filePath=

#number of documents
numberOfDocs=
```

my stacktrace looks like this:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ConsoleApp': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'numberOfDocuments'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:598) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:376) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1404) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:860) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) ~[spring-boot-2.1.15.RELEASE.jar:2.1.15.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) ~[spring-boot-2.1.15.RELEASE.jar:2.1.15.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-2.1.15.RELEASE.jar:2.1.15.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.15.RELEASE.jar:2.1.15.RELEASE]
at ConsoleApp.main(ConsoleApp.java:36) ~[main/:na]
```

What am I missing here? Why is my int property seen as String in application.property ? Do i need to cast int for it to work?

Comment: You specified an empty string which is not the same as a property not being present. Either provide a proper value or remove it to have the default included. An empty string cannot be converted to an `int`. `Integer.valueOf("");` will throw an exception hence it will not be able to convert it.

Comment: Comment out the `numberOfDocs` property if you don't have a value for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the initialization of `numberOfDocs` property in application.properties file.

You have initilized `numbeOfDocs` as `""`(empty string) and spring is trying to convert this empty string to integer, because you declared `numberOfDocuments` as int variable.

Your error will get fixed by one of thre ways

1. Change `numberOfDocuments` data type to `String`
2. Initilize `numberOfDoc` property with valid integer
3. Just remove `numberOfDoc` property from application.properties. Meaning don't initialize it so it will take default value 10

Comment: The error will be fixed by not giving a blank value in the property file, i.e. by removing or commenting the line, so the default of 10 from the annotation can be applied.

Comment: Missed that scenario. I have updated the answer

Comment: @Andreas, thank you so much. I wasnt aware, using a property directly in the "@value" annotation was acceptable without first "declaring" it in application.properties

Comment: @armel Really? The `:10` syntax is specifically for giving a default value for when the property is *not* "declared" in the property file.